# jQuery plugins not working... "Type Error: 'undefined' is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Ruby Rails application which utilizes jQuery, and am trying to load plugins but it is not working; the scripts are loaded in the "correct" order (i.e., jquery, jquery_ujs, plugins, own scripts) but any plugin function (specifically testing niceScroll and jScrollPane) fails with "Type Error: 'undefined' is not a function". In Web Inspector I can see that the plugin scripts are loaded successfully after the jQuery script, but I simply cannot get it to work.

jQuery itselt works completely fine, and in fact Turbolinks and jQuery turbolinks works fine as well. However, trying to call "`$('.something').niceScroll`" (or any other plugin) yields the above-mentioned type error.

Here is my aplication.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require socket.io
//= require jquery.jscrollpane.min
//= require jquery.mousewheel
//= require auctions
```

Which, when placed in the application layout, yields this (partial) html:

```
<head>
  <title>Slamlaunch</title>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/assets/active_admin.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/assets/auctions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/assets/marketing/marketing.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/assets/patches.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/assets/products.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/socket.io.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.mousewheel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/auctions.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param">
<meta content="LzMLqv0Sb7+89JGe0U5x2ZGkECJ4l1gfbiD/81jFJD4=" name="csrf-token">
</head>
```

Also, yes, all of the relevant code is executed either in a $(function(){}) block or in the console, long after all libraries are loaded.

Comment: please provide some code.. sply where the scripts are being loaded

Comment: You should provide some code that is related to where you load these plugins.

Comment: if $ is undefined, either $.noConflict is being called or jquery isn't being included. If <insertpluginname> is undefined, you are either including jQuery twice, or the plugin isn't being included.

Comment: what does `alert(jQuery.jquery);` show?

Comment: `alert(jQuery.jquery)` shows "undefined"

Comment: In the console, doing something like `$('body').append('<script src="/assets/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>')` and then trying `$('body').jScrollPane()` works fine, but that's a rather ugly, "un-rails" way of doing it, and probably hints at some weird problem. jQuery is only being loaded once.

Answer (score 5):

This problem arises mostly because of incorrect loading of script which according to you isn't your case
try putting all the code inside a

```
$(function(){
//your code
})
```

also check to see the jquery isn't being downloaded twice

Comment: My jquery was being downloaded twice!  Thanks Parv and/or Robert!

Comment: My jquery was being downloaded in footer too.  I didn't notice since I didn't write the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all your codes inside the following enclosure. It works then, worked for me. Might be the problem that plugins might not be loaded fully, so for that **"$(document).ready(function(){})"** is called. After that it works like a charm.

```
 (function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){

    //Your plugin functions to be called here.

    });


    })(jquery);
```

If you use **"$(document).ready(function(){})"** in the following

```
$(function(){});
```

It won't work. Don't know why.